# How much you would have to do for being targeted by the persecution in the Pinochet's regime?

Tags: chile

Agusto Pinochet is undoubtably responsible for torture, politice, and state enforced persecution, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_rights_violations_in_Pinochet%27s_Chile) claims that were approximate that there were around 30,000 victims of human rights abuses in Chile, with 40,018 tortured and 2,279 executed.

I understand by what I had read is that Pinochet exclusively persecuted left-wing activists, left-wing groups, left-wing political parties, and other kinds of left-wing social groupings.

**Q:** This practices of state repressions of the Pinochet's regime, were really limited to the left-wing individuals and groups or were other criteria also targeted by the repression of the Pinochet's regime, and what was the minimum criteria for some individual or group for being targeted?

For last there are some requirements for the responses:

1. Do not promote or deny any kind of moral, legal or ethic criteria about the Pinochet's regime.
2. Only hard evidence.

Comment: I doubt that there were carefully defined criteria by which people were targeted by the regime other than being deemed a "threat" by someone.

Comment: Michelle Bachelet seems to have been persecuted for being the daughter of her father. Sheila Cassidy for not reporting a patient to the authorities. Not sure about Charles Horman. This is of course just from a few quick google searches.

Comment: @Jan Seems or was?

Comment: @Erdel von Mises just google it yourself.

Comment: @Jan (1) Never used google as nothing more than the name of the company. (2) The chilenian lawyer Axel Kaiser said that the goverment of Michelle Bachelet was a absoluty awful goverment implemented left-wing economic polices bringing crisis to Chile. And by wikipedia in spanish is stated that she was a part of the Juventud Socialista de Chile since before the coup. So that theory must be discarted.

Comment: @Jan Clearly they consider that Sheila Cassidy did nothing worthty of execution.

Comment: The Case Horman looks like CIA's problem.

Comment: @ErdelvonMises 1) Which search engine do you recommend? 2) Manifestly wrong, if not a blatant lie. If any government on earth was anti-communist, it was Pinochet.

Comment: @Jos 1) Duckduckgo, but it does no matter. 2) Exactly what?

Comment: The whole point of having a dictatorial regime is so that the government doesn't really need a reason to lock someone up (or worse). Requiring [good reasons for imprisonment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habeas_corpus) is for countries with [Rule of Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_law).

Comment: @T.E.D. Is because their Regime is considered dictactorial?, Is considered dictatorial because he targeted persons by political reasons?, Did the the judicial system would have been dissolved by Pinochet?